# React-redux: looping through props and populating components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have a connected React component called Dashboard, which should be populated with Plot components. These components should be created by mapping an array of JSON objects, retrieved and placed into state via an API call, and then mapped to props through a function, mapStateToProps().

The API call is working. mapStateToProps is also working. However, my attempt to map the array of plot JSON objects in props and create a Plot component from each one fails, with the following error: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined

I suspect that what is going on is that, since I have put the relevant mapping code into the render() lifecycle hook, the code is attempting to run before the API call returns. So, there is no property in state for what it's trying to do when it's trying to do it. Is this the case? If so, how can I fix it?

My Plot component:

```
import React from 'react';

const Plot = ({ props }) => {
    return (
        <div className="media">
            <div className="media-left">
                <a href="#">
                    <img className="media-object" src="http://placehold.it/200/550" alt="Placehold" />
                </a>
            </div>
            <div className="media-body">
                <h4 className="media-heading">{props.name}</h4>
                <ul>
                    <li><strong>Grower: </strong> {props.grower}</li>
                    <li><strong>Region: </strong> {props.region}</li>
                    <li><strong>Current State: </strong> {props.currentState}</li>
                    <li><strong>Next State: </strong> {props.nextState}</li>
                    <li><strong>Days To Next State: </strong> {props.daysToNext}</li>
                    <br />
                    <span class="pull-right">
                        <i id="like1" class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up"></i> <div id="like1-bs3"></div>
                        <i id="dislike1" class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-down"></i> <div id="dislike1-bs3"></div>
                    </span>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};

export default Plot;
```

My Dashboard component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import * as actions from '../actions';
import Plot from './plot';

class Dashboard extends Component {
    componentWillMount() {
        this.props.fetchMessage();
        this.props.fetchPlots();
    }

    render() {
        const plots = this.props.plots;
        return (
            <div>
                <span>{this.props.message}</span>
                <div className='container'>
                    {plots.map((plot) => <Plot name={plot.name} grower={plot.grower} region={plot.region} currentState={plot.currentState} nextState={plot.nextState} daysToNext={plot.daysToNext}/>)}
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

function mapStateToProps(state)
{
    return {
        message: state.auth.message,
        plots: state.auth.plots
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, actions)(Dashboard);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
{plots && plots.map((plot) => 
    <Plot 
        name={plot.name} 
        grower={plot.grower} 
        region={plot.region} 
        currentState={plot.currentState} 
        nextState={plot.nextState} 
        daysToNext={plot.daysToNext}
    />
)}
```

Just append a null check before the map function so that it executes only if it has data

Comment: Works great. Unfortunately, there is something wrong with my Plot component-I'm getting this: `Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined`. What could this be? Usually, this error happens when you import a class using curly brackets that was exported as default, but it's not the case here. Any ideas?

Comment: check your data once . this error is coming because of {plot.name}
check if name exists in plot

Comment: It does, indeed.

Comment: double check if plots is an array , then console it iteratee and then check if name exists .

Comment: Plots is an array-like object. When I use Array.from(plots) and iterate, I can see that each component has a name property. But when I try to map this array, I still get the same error.

Comment: can you share the array of object once

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155345/discussion-between-yash-sharma-and-boris-k).